# Delete BLOB data and the space occupied by it

Tags: sql, json, blob, oracle19c

We have Table in which we are storing JSON file in BLOB object in securefile

Datatype :
JSON_FILES BLOB

```
LOB (JSON_FILES) STORE AS SECUREFILE (
  TABLESPACE  J_FILES
  ENABLE      STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK       8192
  NOCACHE
  LOGGING
      STORAGE    (
                  INITIAL          104K
                  NEXT             1M
                  MINEXTENTS       1
                  MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                 ))
```

However when i delete the rows from the table using Delete statement . Rows get deleted but the space taken by BLOB is present in some segment .

```
Delete from FILE_TABLE WHERE FILE_ID Between 10 and 11000


SELECT  SEGMENT_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME, SUM(BYTES) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 SIZE_IN_GB
FROM    DBA_SEGMENTS
WHERE   OWNER = 'ABC'
AND     TABLESPACE_NAME = 'FILES_TABLESPACE'
GROUP BY SEGMENT_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME

SYS_LOB0001543022C00007$$   FILES_TABLESPACE **608.9727783203125**
FILE_TABLE  FILES_TABLESPACE 2.6875
```

Any solution on Oracle 19c

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038792/266304), but the answer there only applies to BasicFile LOBs. I don't think there is a way to shrink your LOB segments - [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adlob/using-oracle-LOBs-storage.html#GUID-57EF50BD-2BC4-4E19-A109-145323D23E42) "Note that the SHRINK option is not supported for SecureFiles LOBs." So, step back and ask why you want to do this; if you add more data later then the existing storage will just be reused. Do you need the space for something else?

Comment: Also you refer to two tablespace names... your `create table` puts the LOBs in `J_FILES`, but your query is against `FILES_TABLESPACE` - but that might just be a mistake hiding real names for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you delete something in a table (segment), the space allocated to the table remains the same in the tablespace you just have more freespace in the table.  Without looking at the manual to check I would expect segments holding blob (or clob) would behave the same way.  Now if you want to shrink a segment to free the space it used, that's a different question.

Depending upon your circumstances, you might get some joy with (credit to oracel-base for the info):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY LOB(lob_column) (SHRINK SPACE);
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY LOB(lob_column) (SHRINK SPACE CASCADE);
```